# How can I add additional search domains to the resolv.conf created by dhclient in CentOS

Tags: linux, dhcp, centos

When my CentOS virtual machine boots it uses DHCP to get an IP address. It also overwrites resolv.conf with the DNS settings provided by the DHCP server. The DHCP server doesn't supply any search domains so I would like to get dhclient to put in a list of search domains when it writes it. How can I configure dhclient to do this?

Answer (score 36):

None of those worked, but the last one was the closest. For Red Hat 6, Use `DOMAIN` instead of `SEARCH` as in the example above and the file location is different.

I modified the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

and changed

```
DOMAIN=domain.com
```

to

```
DOMAIN="domain.com sub.domain.com"
```

and it all worked.

Comment: You should be able to use both `DOMAIN` and `SEARCH` https://github.com/mcr/isc-dhcp/blob/master/common/resolv.c#L68

Comment: This technique of setting DOMAIN also worked for me on CentOS 6.5, even though my resolve.conf is generated by NetworkManager rather than dhclient. The generated resolve.conf file combined my entries with those from the DHCP server.

Answer (score 17):

Also you can add string to /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf like this

```
prepend domain-search "domain1.com", "domain2.com";
```

Note, that this method works with Debian Lenny and Squeeze, too.

Comment: This works, however "append" works the same as "prepend" on CentOS 7, is this a known bug? How do I append?

Answer (score 8):

I managed to work this out in the end. I added a line like the following to `/etc/dhclient-eth0.conf`

```
append domain-name "example.com";
```

Answer (score 6):

This is mostly a note for RHEL7 to reduce trial and error. [Dean's answer](https://superuser.com/a/466912/500826) of using `DOMAIN="domain1.exmaple.com domain2.example.com"` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-device.conf` works. An interesting note is the host's domain that the connection gets from DHCP is always prepended to the search path, even if you leave it out of `DOMAIN=` or put it later in a list for `DOMAIN=`. It looks like `/sbin/dhclient-script` has a bunch of logic related to this.

In my testing, I found that [Philip's suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/374558/500826) of using `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-device.conf` also works, although there is some strange behavior with that, most likely due to that same logic in `/sbin/dhclient-script` that tries to move things around. For instance, neither supercede or prepend work as expected, the host's domain will be first. As a side note on this method, `/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-device.conf` is the generated NetworkManager file and is used by the client. If you have a file in `/etc/dhcp/` that gets read in, you'll see it pasted at the top of the file and a few extra options added below.

Comment: AWS Linux (RHEL), `DOMAIN="your.domain"` didn't work for me, reset after reboot

Answer (score 3):

The `/etc/dhclient-eth0.conf` answer didn't work for me. I don't have an `/etc/dhcp3` directory so I didn't think that was likely to work either.

After examining the `/sbin/dhclient-script` file (which creates `/etc/resolv.conf` on my Centos 5.6 system), I added the SEARCH line below to `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-eth0:`

```
DEVICE=eth0 
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
HWADDR=08:00:24:61:17:AC 
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
SEARCH="example.com sub1.example.com sub2.example.com"
```

Then:

```
# ifdown eth0
# ifup eth0
#  cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search example.com sub1.example.com sub2.example.com
nameserver 10.1.0.11
```

Comment: Note that DOMAIN or SEARCH apparently *must* be added to the ifcfg-eth0 file, and adding it to just sysconfig/network is NOT sufficient -- DESPITE the ifup-post properly sourcing that file.  NetworkManager, that fridge-art of pointless D-K wheel reinvention, will go behind the ifup-post invocation and munge the resolv.conf AFTER ifup-post is done, laying down ONLY the fqdn as SEARCH .  It's obviously ignoring sysconfig/network because, well #boring or something.  \sigh.  Gold star, kids.

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS 6, I'm using the following file to add my preferred DNS search domain:

```
# cat /etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf 
interface "eth0" {
    supersede domain-search "dns1.example.com";
}
# getenforce 
Enforcing
# ls -lZ /etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf 
-rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:bin_t:s0   /etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf
#
```

This file is the first that's checked for in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth`:

```
if [ -s /etc/dhcp/dhclient-${DEVICE}.conf ]; then
   DHCLIENTCONF="-cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient-${DEVICE}.conf";
```

See also: [redhat - Configuring DHCP on RHEL 6 - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/231076/configuring-dhcp-on-rhel-6)

Comment: One note to add - if you're specifying multiple search domains to dhclient by using `(option|supersede|*) domain-search ...`, make sure you follow the `dhcp-options(5)` man page spec for quoting individual domains: `option domain-search "example.com", "sales.example.com", "eng.example.com";` Many older distributions of dhclient allowed the format `"example.com sales.example.com eng.example.com";` but this compatibility has been removed in the past few years due to bug fixes https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/777785

Answer (score 2):

For anyone going through Fedora / Red Hat's rather opaque pile of scripts, the answer, at least on Amazon's latest AMI, it is /etc/dhclient-eth0.conf (and not the decoy empty folder at /etc/dhcp/ ). The file is not present and will need to be created

Comment: Adding SEARCH to ifcfg-eth0/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 also works on the Amazon version of Fedora. In older versions of Red Hat it apparently was DOMAIN. I wpould recommend this over the above.

Answer (score 1):

Add to the DHCP server conf (ISC dhcpd):

```
option domain-name "domain1.com domain2.net domain3.org";
```

Where `domain1.com, etc..` are the domain suffixes you want added to the `resolv.conf` file on each client.

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora 19 add next lines to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

```
# /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

interface "p2p1"
{
    supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
    append domain-name " mydomain.net example.com";
}
```

Work fine with NetworkManager. Details see: `# man  dhclient.conf`

Comment: does not work for aws linux (rhel)

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't see this answer and it worked for me (while the others didn't), here it is: edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` the same way as you would `/etc/resolv.conf`. You'll need `resolvconf` installed.